# Temp gage randomly stops working while driving and ac doesn’t work. 2015 Chevy cruze

Tags: ac, sensor

I have a 2015 Chevy Cruze and randomly my temp gage stops working and my ac doesn’t run. I changed both the coolant sensors and if I disconnect the battery and reconnect it then everything runs correctly but I have to do that probably at least once a day. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your vehicle is probably setting a code for some type of coolant sensor fault. That code then disables the AC and makes the fans run on high because the car is in a limp mode. If the car doesn't know the coolant temp it will do everything it can to cool itself down including not get hot like running the AC. Disconnecting the battery clears the code and gets you out of limp mode.

check the code and diagnose as prescribed. If I had to guess it is a wiring problem.